# Cannot install Pillow on Windows (Offline)

Tags: python, django

I downloaded the Pillow package from:
https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

The latest version is 6.2.1. But when I try to install it to my offline-computer, it gives the error:

*The header or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling pillow from source*

Then i tried downloading and installing it into my Internet connected PC and copied the installed folder in my venv to the offline system and placed it on the correct path (lib/site-packages).

But when I run the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It gives the same error again. My current Python version is 3.7.

Comment: Can't you just run `pip install pillow` on the PC?

Comment: You are missing libraries to compile the binary part of Pillow on your machine. They are usually installed with the systems package manager.

Comment: So what should I do? I did try to install Pillow locally by downloading the tar.gz package but it doesn't give any error. And when I try to migrate it says its not installed.